# Best option for calculating distance/similarity for structured data with both categorical and numerical dimensions?

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, similarities, mixed-type-data

Say you have individual one with the following attributes:

{age: 25, gender: Male, education: Bachelor's, residence: California, salary: 65,000}.

Individual two has the following attributes:

{age: 27, gender: Female, Education: Master's, residence: California, salary: 60,000}.

What is a sound way of quantifying the similarity between them while reconciling the presence of both numerical and categorical data points?